# How to implement row reorder by a position field on listing in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, dynamic-rows, listing-component

I found [this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/pattern-library/displaying-data/datatable/datatable.html) on **magento2 documentation** and I am trying to do a **row sorting** by a field named position like this image in the link:
[image]

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

in your `DataProvider` Class in charge to give you all the data (I assume you have already it), you need to sort your collection like `$myCollection->setOrder('my_position','ASC')->getItems()`
Hope it helps.